# amsplain or amsalpha not working with Bibtex

Tags: bibtex, amsplain

My references are cited correctly if I use any of the following styles with **BibTex**: **plain**, **unsrt** or **alpha**. However, if I change the style to **amsplain** or **amsalpha**, none of the references are cited in the text (in their places there is a blank), though the reference list is correctly formatted for both of the styles. Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong? I use Tex Live 2022. Thank you all in advance!

There goes a small complete document.

```
\documentclass[editMode]{ufdissertation}\sloppy
%\usepackage{CustomMacros}%  This is a user macro/style file.

\usepackage{tikz}%       tikz is used by almost everyone, but 
certainly by me for this.
\usepackage{pgfplots}%   pgfplots is tikz but better.
%\usepackage{amsrefs}%   amsrefs contains the .bibtex style content for mathematician papers.
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\usepackage{scrextend}
\deffootnote{1.5em}{0em}{\thefootnotemark\quad}
%% Uncomment the relevant line below if you have tables or figures.
\haveTablestrue%        Uncomment this if you have tables in your thesis.
\haveFigurestrue%       Uncomment this if you have figures in your thesis.
\haveObjectstrue%       Uncomment this if you have Objects in your thesis. This is almost certainly not the case however.
%%% Below are the commands to set the degree type, department, graduation time, and chair. 
%       Most of these are self explanatory. 
%       Note: The \chair command takes an optional argument for a cochair. 
%           So if John was your chair and Jacob was a cochair, you would use \chair[Jacob]{John}.
%           If John was your chair and you had no cochair, you can simply use \chair{John}.
\title{any}%  Put your title here.
\degreeType{any}%   Official name of your degree; eg "Doctorate of Philosophy".
\major{any}%                    Your official Department
\author{any}%                  Your Name
\thesisType{any}%              Dissertation (PhD) or Thesis (Masters)
\degreeYear{any}%                      Intended graduation year (not the year you submit the thesis)
\degreeMonth{any}%                   Month of graduation should be May, August, or December.
\chair{any}%                   Chair and Cochair (see comment block above).

%%% For each of the following, type in the name of the file that contains each section. 
% They are assumed to be tex files, but if they aren't the command takes an optional argument for the extension.
%So, you could load dedication.tex as your dedication file using \setDedicationFile{dedication}
% You could load dedication.txt instead with \setDedicationFile[txt]{dedication}.

% NOTE: For some compilers they may or may not add a .tex to the end of the file automatically.
% If you get a "couldn't find dedication.tex.tex" type error, try the command with an empty optional argument,
%e.g. \setDedicationFile[]{dedication}

%%% These are REQUIRED sections; easiest to do via these commands.

\setDedicationFile{dedicationFile}%                 Dedication Page
\setAcknowledgementsFile{acknowledgementsFile}%     Acknowledgements Page
\setAbstractFile{abstractFile}%                     Abstract Page (This should only include the abstract itself)
\setReferenceFile{referenceFile}{amsplain}%         References. 
First argument is your bibtex source file
%                                                       the second argument is your bibtex style file.
\setBiographicalFile{biographyFile}%                Biography file of the Author (you).

%%% These are NOT required, so only use them if you actually need/have them.

\setAbbreviationsFile{abbreviations}%           Abbreviations Page
\setAppendixFile{appendix}%                     Appendix Content; hyperlinking might be weird.
\multipleAppendixtrue%                          Uncomment this if you have more than one appendix, 
%                                                   comment it if you have only one appendix.
\begin{document}

This author \cite{Author} did something and this author \cite{Author2} did something else.

\end{document}
```

Here is the content of dedicationFile:

```
Anything.
```

Here is the content of acknowledgementsFile:

```
Anything.
```

Here is the content of abstractFile:

```
Anything.
```

Here is the content of referenceFile:

```
@article{Author,
title={Title},
volume={1},
number={1},
journal={Journal},
publisher={Publisher},
author={Somebody, John},
year={2000},
pages={1-2}
}

@article{Author2,
title={Title},
volume={1},
number={1},
journal={Journal},
publisher={Publisher},
author={Somebody Else, John},
year={2000},
pages={1-2}
}
```

Here is the content of biographyFile:

```
Anything.
```

Here is the content of abbreviations:

```
\singlespacing
\begin{tabular}{l p{5in}} 
\emph{a} & Piston acceleration.\\
\\
$A_{\mathrm{in}}$ & Piston internal annular area.\\
\end{tabular}
\doublespacing
```

Here is the content of appendix:

```
\chapter{Some Additional Material}

Test for first appendix file.

\begin{table}[h]
\caption[Aliquam mi nisi]{Aliquam mi nisi, tristique at rhoncus quis, consectetur non mi. Phasellus blandit quam ligula, a viverra lacus commodo at.}
%\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXXX}\hline
Some    & Data  & Goes  & Here\\\hline
Some    & Data  & Goes  & Here\\
Some    & Data  & Goes  & Here\\
Some    & Data  & Goes  & Here\\\hline
\end{tabularx}
%\end{center}

\end{table}


\chapter{Secondary Appendix Content}

Test for second appendix file.


\chapter{Expert Opinions}

Test for third appendix file.
```

Comment: as always, you should show a small complete document that demonstrates the problem

Comment: Sorry for that. I edited my post and included a small document.

Comment: Do you have a link for the `ufdissertation` class? This is not one of the standard classes so we need to know where we can find it.

Comment: Also, can you provide the Bibtex entries for the `Author` and `Author2` citations?

Comment: I have the ufdissertation file in my computer. Can I upload it here?

Comment: I downloaded the class from the University site, tried your file and compiled it. It works and produces the references.

Comment: Interesting, @egreg. I just noticed that if I hover the mouse cursor over the place in the text where the references are supposed to be cited, it changes to a little hand and I can click on the empty space and be directed to the reference list at the end of the document. But the citations themselves don't appear in the text (they are empty spaces).

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. In the last comment I was referencing the .pdf file, and not the .tex file.

Comment: OK, I found a solution. I simply changed the class I was using to its newest version, and everything worked smoothly! Thank you all very much for your help!